# How to use tranwrd in a data step?

Tags: sas

I try to substitute `y` for `x`
I tried to used `tranwrd` function in the data step . However the result is only one row

```
data test2 ; 
set test  ;
address =  tranwrd(address , 'y' , 'x' ) ;   
put address ;
run;
```

---

test data as follows

```
    id  address
    1   123 y street
    2   234 y street
    3   345 street
```

Comment: get rid of `put` line

Comment: thanks i dont know why it works now. i tried initially without put

Answer (score 0):

The code, as written, should work. However removing the `put` line will prevent each line being written to the log (this will speed things up if you have a large data set):

```
data test2 ; 
set test  ;
address =  tranwrd(address , 'y' , 'x' ) ;   
run;
```

The `address =  tranwrd(address , 'y' , 'x' ) ;` adequately defines the variable value.

The `put` statement writes the value of `address` to the SAS log at that point in the DATA STEP.

You can read more about the `put` statement here : http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi27/p104-27.pdf